# How do I pass data from Vue Instance to a Single File Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been working with Vue for sometime, but I've never really tried working with Single File Components alongside webpack. Here's the problem I'm having. I have 2 files: main.js (which contains the Vue root instance) and App.vue (which is a single file component. The code in each file goes as thus:

main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App, },
  data(){
    return {
        greeting: "Hello World!",
     }
  },
  render: h => h(App),

});
```

App.vue:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{greeting}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  
  }
  
 </script>
```

Please note that I'm using webpack, and the main.js file is meant to be an entry point. The code is bundled to a file called bundle.js.

Now, my problem is that, when the template in App.vue renders, it doesn't show "Hello Word", which is the value of {{greeting}}. I expect that data passed from the root Vue instance in main.js should be available to the App.vue component.

The {{greeting}} isn't evaluated when I put it in my index.html file, which links to bundle.js (the bundled version of main.js)

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Nothing</title>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
      {{greeting}}

  </body>
</html>
```

Does this mean that data in the root vue instance isn't available anywhere? What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The `greeting` needs to be in your component's `data`. This has nothing to do with SFC (Single File Components), it's just the way Vue's templates work: they read from the component's data.

So what you need to do is move the `data` to the appropriate component, which is tied with the template where you're trying to use.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ greeting }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return { greeting: 'Hello World!', }
  },
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew this. I was only given an example of the problem I'm facing. There are some kind of data I need to store in the root instance so that I can make it available to many components all at once. How would I do this? It's not working.

Comment: You cannot randomly access from the parent component. Pass it as a prop to the child components as usual. Alternatively, you can access the `this.$root`. Again, none of these has to do with the fact that you're working with SFC. I suggest going over Vue's official tutorials.